# What is the difference between IRI-Playbook and IRI full node (Private tangle)?

Tags: iri-node, transaction, iota-network, iri-legacy-api, iota-cli

I know there is three type of full node:
1- mainnet
2- devnet
3- testnet

I wand to build private IoTA network with full control.

So, I have found tutorial for private tangle:
https://docs.iota.org/docs/compass/0.1/how-to-guides/set-up-a-private-tangle

and also I have found these is IRI-Playbook:
https://iri-playbook.readthedocs.io/en/feat-docker/getting-started-quickly.html

I confused about the difference between them?

Comment: Erm, iri-playbook installs an iri node that is part of the public mainnet, doesn't it? or is there some playbook for private tangles, too that I'm missing?

Comment: @mihi, yes it is... Does it mean it can not be used in private IoTA and be used as my own node and add only my only neighbors?

Comment: For a private tangle, you will need to use a different Coordinator address than the mainnet uses. You can change this regardless how you installed your node (or whether you are using iri or hornet), but I don't think the playbook covers that or provides automation for it. When you just install iri and do not change the coordinator address, and not peer with any other mainnet node either, you won't see any confirmed transactions, ever.